# Finding running time of program

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm

I am new to Algorithms and DS. I am referring to a book and it has some questions given which I am having difficulty understanding.

I am required to find the running time of the following programs: (the comments are from book only)

```
function(int n) {
    for(int i=1;i<=n/3;i++) { // will execute n/3 time
        for(int j=1;j<=n;j+=4) { // will execute n/4 times
            printf("*");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer: O(n^2)

How is it n^2? The first loop will execute for n/3 times and the second one for n/4. n/3 * n/4 = n^2/12. How is it n^2? Please help me understand.

Question 2

```
function(int n) {
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) { // will execute n times
        for(int j=i;j<i*i;j+=4) { // will execute n*n times ?????? (How?) 
            if(j%i==0) {
                for(int k=0;k<j;k++) { // will execute j times
                    printf("*");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer: O(n^5)

The first loop executes for n times. Fine.

How does the second loop execute for n * n times? Here, the value of j is initialized to i, so shouldn't it be (n * n)-i times? If j was initialized to 0, it would have been n * n times, right?

The third loop executes j times because k

Please help me understand why 2nd loop (j) will execute n*n times. Thank you.

Comment: I'd suggest reading up on the Big-Oh notation. O(n^2) is not the same as n^2, and you are treating them as if they were.

Comment: Can you suggest a book or blog/website for absolute beginners regarding the Big-Oh notation? Thanks.

Comment: gentle reminder: big O notation is not a run-time estimation (per the title), but rather a complexity estimate.  Typically, an O(0) algorithm (to accomplish some effort) will finish sooner than an O(n) algorithm (to accomplish the same effort), but NOT always.

Answer (score 0):

The book deals with big-Oh. A complete introduction to big-Oh would be too long, but in big-Oh-land it holds that:

```
O(a*f(n)) = O(f(n))
```

with `a` a constant.

another one is that:

```
O(a_k * n^k+ a_(k-1) n^(k-1)+...+a_0) = O(n^k)
```

with `f(n)` a random function.

---

About the **second question**: the second loop runs from `i` to `i*i`. Now since `i` will reach `n-1` it has size `O(n)`, thus the loop will be executed in the last run `(n-1)*(n-1)` times. Since `j` will eventually reach something of the order `O(n^2)` and the third loop runs from `0` to `j-1`, the third (most inner) loop has a time complexity of `O(n^2)` as well. This thus means that the total time complexity of the loops is:

```
O(n)*O(n^2)*O(n^2)=O(n^5)
```

Comment: Can you suggest a book or blog/website for absolute beginners regarding the Big-Oh notation? Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you can start with the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) article. *Computational complexity, a modern approach* is a free book about complexity-theory and big-oh, but is somehow advanced. And there is also [this](http://web.mit.edu/16.070/www/lecture/big_o.pdf) document from MIT.